# Image is rotated when it is taken as a photo

Tags: android

When I took the picture and place them on the imageview, it getting rotated.

I am checking the orientation but returns 0, I have no clue now how to handle this issue.

While I have been debugging, I recorded url as follows just in case if someone can able to help.

```
 url = "/storage/emulated/0/3dd5ea68-c9b7-4103-ac01-67ce72bccf8f.png"
```

The logic is as follows:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(url);
 try {
    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(url);
    int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
    Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    if (orientation == 6) {
        matrix.postRotate(90);
    }
    else if (orientation == 3) {
        matrix.postRotate(180);
    }
    else if (orientation == 8) {
        matrix.postRotate(270);
    }
    Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true); // rotating bitmap

    mMemoryCache.put(url, rotatedBitmap);
    view.setLocalImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
```

Comment: You might want to upload a sample image somewhere and link to it from your question. Put the image somewhere that will not cause it to be modified, so EXIF headers and stuff remain intact. Then, also take a screenshot of what you're seeing when you try using that image, and add that screenshot to your question. This will allow others to work with a piece of the same data that you are.

Comment: I have added image url path, please see update.

Comment: Yes, but we do not have that image. Also note that PNG images do not have EXIF headers, though JPEG images do.

Comment: How could I able to bring that image into the question? I am not making the image as a png, os does it automatically. I use LG android phone.

Comment: I have even changed it to jpeg, but the result is same. it still rotates.